# PHP - How to get the value of json api using Php?

Tags: php, json, api

I have a question regarding on json.. I tried to get an api from other site and downloaded it as json file..I've already decoded this file using this code below..

```
$str = file_get_contents('../trelloApi.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
```

From this image attached, how do I get or print the value of the [list] => Array, [board] => Array and [card] => Array?

[image: json decoded]

Please help me :(

Comment: What is the content of your json array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that the api return a array of arrays, then use foreach to iterate through the json_decode.

```
foreach ($json as $ticket) {
    // if your $ticket['data'] is a StdClass, force to be array
    $ticket['data'] = (array)$ticket['data'];

    // now you can access your indexes
    $list = $ticket['data']['list'];
    $board = $ticket['data']['board'];
    $card = $ticket['data']['card'];
}
```

If you don't like your `$ticket['data']` as array, use as object instead `$ticket['data']->list, $ticket['data']->board...`

Comment: Thank you for your great time..I followed your code but i got this error message **Illegal string offset 'id'**,**Illegal string offset 'name'**,**Illegal string offset 'list'**,**Illegal string offset 'board'** and **"Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"**

Comment: `$ticket['data']` isn't an array, then you can use `$ticket['data']->list` or force `$ticket['data']` to be array like as `$data = (array) $ticket['data']`

Answer (score 1):

After json_decode you can this way retrieve 'list','board' and 'card' array data....May be help you..

```
$list=array();
$board=array();
$card=array();

foreach($json as $key => $value){

   $list[]=$value[$key]['data']['list'];
   $board[]=$value[$key]['data']['board'];
   $card[]=$value[$key]['data']['card'];    
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
print_r($board);
print_r($card);
```

Comment: Thank you for your great time..I followed your code but i got this error message **Illegal string offset 'id'**,**Illegal string offset 'name'**,**Illegal string offset 'list'**,**Illegal string offset 'board'**

Comment: I got this error also "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 0):

You can access list array like below:

`$list = $json['data']['list']`

So access board array:

`$board = $json['data']['board']`

To access card array:

`$card = $json['data']['card']`

Answer (score 0):

You get access for only 173 locaions array:

```
$list = $json[173]['data']['list'];
$board = $json[173]['data']['board'];
$card = $json[173]['data']['card'];

print_r($list);
print_r($board);
print_r($card);
```

you can get all of the array like

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) { 
    $list[] = $value['data']['list'];
    $board[] = $value['data']['board'];
    $card[] = $value['data']['card'];
}

print_r($list);
print_r($board);
print_r($card);
```

Comment: Thank you for your great time..I followed your code but i got this error message **Illegal string offset 'id'**,**Illegal string offset 'name'**,**Illegal string offset 'list'**,**Illegal string offset 'board'** and **"Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"**

Comment: @jhovyn do not forget to add your `$str = file_get_contents('../trelloApi.json');` and `$json = json_decode($str, true);` lins

Comment: Yes sir I did that..see my code '<?php

$url = 'http://localhost:8080/trello/trello.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data,true); 

$list = $json[173]['data']['list'];
$board = $json[173]['data']['board'];
$card = $json[173]['data']['card'];

print_r($list);
print_r($board);
print_r($card);

?>'

Comment: try second part of my answare @jhovyn

Comment: I got this error Sir **Illegal string offset data,card,list,board**,**Undefined index: data**,**Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => S [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => 5 [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => h.......**